# How does the secret room system work in Torchlight 2?

Tags: torchlight-2

I wonder how the secret room system work.

1. Do secret rooms exist in the "main world" or only in instances?
2. Is there a limit of how many secret rooms that can be generated for each area/instance? An instance can have several levels, is there always a secret room for each level? What determines the amount of secret rooms?
3. How many different types of secret room door-opening-mechanisms are there?
4. What determines the content of a secret room?

Comment: So far I've seen vine bridges extending, using a detonator to destroy a rock wall, and a third one which I can't remember.

Comment: @SaintWacko I have seen picture-frames or tablets on walls that you can click on as well.

Comment: Ooh, I'll have to keep an eye out for those.

Comment: I've also seen some "secret areas" that don't apparently get registered as such. For example, there are some hidden valves in various places in the final act (right before you battle the final boss) that open up hidden closets containing a chest or a large pile of gold.

Comment: I don't quite have anything to add that other people haven't mentioned, but I did want to say, that I recently was in an instance where you had to hit 4 gongs, they were scattered around the an open area in Act 2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay, so feel free to edit this.

#### Do secret rooms exist in the "main world" or only in instances?

I have only found secret rooms in instanced dungeons.

#### Is there a limit of how many secret rooms that can be generated for each area/instance?

So far, I think I have have found a max of 3 secret rooms in a single floor inside of a dungeon. Those were real secret rooms, not associated with that dungeon (like the broken detonators that require plungers to work etc.)

#### An instance can have several levels, is there always a secret room for each level?

I haven't found a secret in every level of an instance, but I could have missed them.

#### How many different types of secret room door-opening-mechanisms are there?

We have found three so far:

- vine bridges extending *(instance specific?)*
- using a detonator to destroy a rock wall *(instance specific?)*
- clickable picture-frames or tablets on walls *(instance specific?)*

#### What determines the content of a secret room?

I have no idea, but I suspect it's automatically generated somehow.

Comment: Do the clickable things always hightlight when moused over?

Answer (score 4):

1. Only in instances as far as I've seen.
2. I just found a dungeon with 4 secret rooms on a single level (though there may have been more I missed). I also find dungeons with no secret rooms (though again, I may just be missing them).
3. I've seen detonators blowing up a wall, breaking specific vases to open up a vine bridge, tablets on walls, levers, and not sure what else. Oh, and some where you just walk farther then the minimap shows you can go.
4. No idea how it works, sorry (except I've had hidden rooms with amazing loot, and hidden rooms with virtually nothing. I'm assuming it's random, just like most of the rest of the loot in this game).

Answer (score 4):

In dungeons that have the blue crystals and large vines/roots, often secret rooms are accessed by breaking a **"Urn" next to a row of teeth like vines**.  Just like other Urns, the text "Urn" appears above it, but it is unique in that it has green lights and smoke and is next to the row of vine stubs.  Sometimes the Urn is on your side of the bridge, and **sometimes it's on the other  side, making it easy to not notice**, and you must hold shift+fire to break it:

[image: Secret path urn]
[image: Secret path appears after]

Answer (score 3):

There are also sometimes secret pathways you can find by walking along the edge and sort of pulling your character so they are 'running into' the wall or trees or what have you. I found one that takes you to a Dragon Shrine which gives you +5% magic-finding luck for 5 minutes this way.